# Using context managers without "with" block

Tags: python, block, with-statement, contextmanager

Below is an example of my `my_create` method, and an example of that method in use.

```
@contextmanager
def my_create(**attributes):
    obj = MyObject(**attributes)
    yield obj
    obj.save()

with my_create(a=10) as new_obj:
     new_obj.b = 7

new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.b  # => 7
new_obj.is_saved()  # => True
```

To users of Ruby/Rails, this may look familiar.  It's similar to the `ActiveRecord::create` method, with the code inside the `with` block acting as, well, a block.

**However:**

```
with my_create(a=10) as new_obj:
    pass

new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.is_saved()  # => True
```

In the above example, I've passed an empty "block" to my `my_create` function.  Things work as expected (`my_obj` was initialized, and saved), but the formatting looks a little wonky, and the `with` block seems unnecessary.

I would prefer to be able to call `my_create` directly, without having to setup a `pass`ing `with` block. Unfortunately, that's not possible with my current implementation of `my_create`.

```
my_obj = create(a=10)
my_obj  # => <contextlib.GeneratorContextManager at 0x107c21050>
```

I'd have to call both `__enter__` and `__exit__` on the `GeneratorContextManager` to get my desired result.

**The question:**

Is there a way to write my `my_create` function so that it can be called with a "block" as an optional "parameter"?  I don't want to pass an optional function to `my_create`.  I want `my_create` to *optionally* yield execution to a block of code.

The solution doesn't have to involve `with` or `contextmanager`.  For instance, the same results as above can be achieved with a `generator` and a `for` loop, although the syntax becomes even more unclear.

At this point I'm afraid that a readable-enough-to-be-sensibly-usable solution doesn't exist, but I'm still interested to see what everyone comes up with.

**Some clarification:**

Another example would be:

```
@contextmanager
def header_file(path):
    touch(path)
    f = open(path, 'w')
    f.write('This is the header')
    yield f
    f.close()

with header_file('some/path') as f:
    f.write('some more stuff')

another_f = header_file('some/other/path')
```

I always want to do the `__enter__` and `__exit__` parts of the context manager.  I don't always want to supply a block.  I don't want to have to set up a `pass`ing `with` block if I don't have to.

This is possible and easy in Ruby.  It would be cool if it were possible in Python too, since we're already so close (we just have to set up a `pass`ing `with` block).  I understand that the language mechanics make it a difficult (technically impossible?) but a close-enough solution is interesting to me.

Comment: My inspiration for this question, if anyone's interested: http://wiki.c2.com/?BlocksInPython

Comment: You need to wrap yield obj with try finally for exception safety.

Comment: not relying on `@contextmanager` and defining your own `__enter__` and `__exit__` alongside a method that could be used when the block isn't given might be an option.

Answer (score 7):

Add a new method on `MyObject` which creates *and* saves.

```
class MyObject:

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **attributes):
        obj = cls(**attributes)
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

This is an alternate initializer, a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), and the design pattern has precedent in Python standard libraries and in many popular frameworks.  [Django models use this pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model) where an alternate initializer `Model.create(**args)` can offer additional features that the usual `Model(**args)` would not (e.g. persisting to the database).

> Is there a way to write my my_create function so that it can be called with a "block" as an optional "parameter"?

No.

Comment: I'm aware that `create` methods like this exist but it's not really answering my question. sorry if the question wasn't too clear.

Comment: OK, I've just edited to provide the answer to your literal question.

Comment: Thanks wim, but you're answer is too short for community guidelines?

Comment: @j0eb: No no no no nopity nope nope no. Python is not Ruby. Passing blocks around is not a thing in Python, and `yield` means something completely different from in Ruby. No.

Comment: @j0eb  You said "*the solution doesn't have to involve with or contextmanager*".  I have offered you a Pythonic solution.  Not sure what more you're asking for here.

Comment: See here for extended discussion about the topic: http://wiki.c2.com/?BlocksInPython

Comment: @wim Feel free to refer to example solution if you'd like.

Comment: @user2357112 . Actually `yield` means nearly the same thing as it does in Ruby.  During the execution of some code (A loop, A context setup/teardown) yield some object to some other block of code (A ruby block or the python block inside your for or with statement) and then potentially pick up the return value.  Continue execution of the original code.

Comment: @j0eb: No, `yield` means something entirely different. In Ruby, `yield` means "call the block". In Python, `yield` means that the function is a generator function, and that the generator's stack frame should be suspended and removed from the stack, and `next` or `send` should return the argument given to `yield`.

Comment: A Python function with `yield` behaves fundamentally differently from a function without `yield`, even if the only `yield` is an `if False: yield` that never executes. Ruby's `yield` doesn't change a function so deeply.

Comment: @user2357112 I think you're oversimplifying the ruby side and overcomplicating the python side. Both yield statements yield some object to some other block of code before resuming execution.  Thats their essential purpose.  The mechanics of execution transfer may be different but its incorrect to call them "completely different".

Comment: True there is the generator/function dichotomy but we're not asking "Are python functions and python generators different?".  Generators aren't that different from Ruby functions that yield.  Its just that you pretty much need to put that generator in a `with` or `for` block to be usefull.  Of course you could go calling `next` but that's a little odd and generally not used.

Comment: But it sounds like you do know a lot about the topic so I'd love to see an answer to the original question.

Comment: The essential difference is that ruby yield doesn't yield unless there's something to yield to which I guess is the whole point of this question

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there seems to be some confusion so I've been forced to come up with an example solution.  Here's the best I've been able to come up with so far.

```
class my_create(object):
    def __new__(cls, **attributes):
        with cls.block(**attributes) as obj:
            pass

        return obj

    @classmethod
    @contextmanager
    def block(cls, **attributes):
        obj = MyClass(**attributes)
        yield obj
        obj.save()
```

If we design `my_create` like above, we can use it normally without a block:

```
new_obj = my_create(a=10)
new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.is_saved()  # => True
```

And we can call it *slightly* differently with a block.

```
with my_create.block(a=10) as new_obj:
    new_obj.b = 7

new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.b  # => 7
new_obj.saved  # => True
```

Calling `my_create.block` is kind of similar to calling Celery tasks `Task.s`, and users who don't want to call `my_create` with a block just call it normally, so I'll allow it.

However, this implementation of `my_create` looks wonky, so we can create a wrapper to make it more like the implementation of `context_manager(my_create)` in the question.

```
import types

# The abstract base class for a block accepting "function"
class BlockAcceptor(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls.block(*args, **kwargs) as yielded_value:
            pass

        return yielded_value

    @classmethod
    @contextmanager
    def block(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

# The wrapper
def block_acceptor(f):
    block_accepting_f = type(f.func_name, (BlockAcceptor,), {})
    f.func_name = 'block'
    block_accepting_f.block = types.MethodType(contextmanager(f), block_accepting_f)
    return block_accepting_f
```

Then `my_create` becomes:

```
@block_acceptor
def my_create(cls, **attributes):
    obj = MyClass(**attributes)
    yield obj
    obj.save()
```

In use:

```
# creating with a block
with my_create.block(a=10) as new_obj:
    new_obj.b = 7

new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.b  # => 7
new_obj.saved  # => True


# creating without a block
new_obj = my_create(a=10)
new_obj.a  # => 10
new_obj.saved  # => True
```

Ideally the `my_create` function wouldn't need to accept a `cls`, and the `block_acceptor` wrapper would handle that, but I haven't got time to make those changes just now.

pythonic? no. useful? possibly?

I'm still interested to see what others come up with.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using different functions to get a context manager that saves an object on `__exit__` and to get an automatically saved object. There's no easy way to have one function do both things. (There are no "blocks" that you can pass around, other than functions, which you say you don't want.)

For instance, you could create a second function that just creates and immediately saves an object without running any extra code to run in between:

```
def create_and_save(**args):
    obj = MyObject(**args)
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

So you could make it work with two functions. But a more Pythonic approach would probably be to get rid of the context manager function and make the `MyObject` class serve as its own context manager. You can give it very simple `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
    if exception_type is None:
        self.save()
```

Your first example would become:

```
with MyObject(a=10) as new_obj:
     new_obj.b = 7
```

You could also turn the `create_and_save` function I showed above into a `classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def create_and_save(cls, **args):
    obj = cls(**args)
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

Your second example would then be:

```
new_obj = MyObject.create_and_save(a=10)
```

Both of those methods could be written in a base class and simply inherited by other classes, so don't think you'd need to rewrite them all the time.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.  I've updated my question with "some clarification" because it seems this is more tailored to a single purpose "I want to be able to create and save an object problem".

Comment: Your `header_file` function is actually another example of putting the context manager in the wrong place. Files are already context managers (which close themselves in `__exit__`). So make `header_file` a normal function that returns an open file to which it has written a header line. Then you can either use it in a `with` statement (with the file being the context manager), or just call the function and call `close` on the file afterwards yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But then I have to call `close` on the file afterwards myself.  Now my file isn't being context managed, I'm manually managing context JUST because I didn't want to do any extra handling of the file, like say, writing `'some more stuff'` to it.

Comment: It's like, as soon as I don't want to do anything inside the `with` block, I have to manage all of my context all of a sudden, or put an ungoldy `with`-`pass` block in my code.

Comment: Or I have to break DRY and repeat all of my methods so that they are wrapped as ContextManagers, or they do the _exact same thing_ except they don't have that one little yield statement that makes them work as context managers

Answer (score 1):

With a slight change, you can can really close to what you want, just not via implementation using `contextlib.contextmanager`:

```py
creator = build_creator_obj()

# "with" contextmanager interface
with creator as obj:
     obj.attr = 'value'

# "call" interface
obj = creator(attr='value')
```

Where `creator` is an object that implements `__enter__` and `__exit__` for the first usage and implements `__call__` for the second usage.

You can also hide the construction of `creator` inside a `property` on some persistent object, e.g.:

```py
class MyDatabase():
    @property
    def create(self):
        return build_creator_obj()

db = MyDatabase()

# so that you can do either/both:
with db.create as obj:
  obj.attr = 'value'

obj = db.create(attr='value')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no solution without needing at least two different call signatures.

Here is a solution that uses a flag inside `create()`:

```py
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.saved = True
        self.in_context = False

    def __enter__(self):
        if not self.in_context:
            raise TypeError(f"Context manager only supported with MyObject::create(..., in_context=True)")

        self.saved = False
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.saved = True
        self.in_context = False

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, a, b, in_context=False):
        product = cls(a, b)
        product.in_context = in_context
        return product

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return isinstance(other, MyObject) and self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
```

```py
>>> with MyObject.create(1, 2, in_context=True) as product:
...     product.a=2
... 
>>> assert product == MyObject.create(2, 2)
>>> assert product.saved

>>> # We don't want this to work outside of MyObject::create()
>>> with product:
...     product.a=3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __enter__
TypeError: Context manager only supported with MyObject::create(..., in_context=True)

>>> # Should fail since in_context is False
>>> with MyObject.create(1, 2) as product:
...     product.a=2
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __enter__
TypeError: Context manager only supported with MyObject::create(..., in_context=True)
```

However you could implement without `in_context` at all as long as you don't mind that `with MyObject()` and `with MyObject.create()` behaves the same.